# Get all CustomControllers with their properties values in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, reflection

I have created several custom controllers like this:

```
public abstract class CustomController: Controller
{
    public abstract string Title { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

```
public class TestController : CustomController
{
    public const string TitleConst = "Tutorial Const";
    public static string TitleStatic = "Tutorial Static";
    public sealed override string Title { get; set; }

    public TestController()
    {
        Title = "Tutorial";
    }
    //...
}
```

And now I want to get all of this custom controllers  and their properties, or at least constants or static properties

How I can get one of the titles:

```
var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(x => typeof(CustomController).IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name,
        Title = // I want to get one of the titles
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? Where these controller be placed could explain a more details?

Comment: I want to get one of the titles

Comment: `((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(x)).Title` or something similar. You need to create an instance so that the constructor fills the `Title` and then read the title from the instance

Comment: Could you tell what's `IndicatorController` ?

Comment: Cannot dynamically create an abstract class @Wiktor Zychla

Comment: That's because the abstract class, `CustomController` is also get there (it's also assignable from itself). Please correct the `Where` filter to exclude it (like `&& !x.IsAbstract`)